# Hangout app in Android

Tags: android, google-hangouts

I'm trying to embedded a video call provided from google hangout in my android app.

I don't know if this is possible, but I've done a lot of research and couldn't find anything.

Is it possible? If not, how do i make an app that has video chat capabilities?

Comment: What have you tried so far..Show your research which you did then I will proceed to help you

Comment: Well, right now I'd really like to use Google Hangouts for hosting the video chat, and I've found the API, but it looks like it's only for web applications. So I really just want to know if it's possible first.

I've found some places saying it's not possible, but they are old and I'm wondering if it has been implemented since then.

Comment: Video chat is possible as Skype also have this feature and many apps etc

Comment: Yeah, I had heard that Skype allowed you to embed a video chat in your application, but can't find anything about Google Hangouts in apps

Comment: Also, this needs to be done using some existing server for hosting the video chat